# Concept of JUNIT

Tags: junit

First of all I would appreciate you looking at this question and taking time to response back. I am a QA (not strong development background) trying to understand how JUNIT works. This was my first effort. I have written a simple calculator which works

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator {

  Scanner userInput= new Scanner(System.in);

  public int cAdd(){
    System.out.println("Enter 1st number: ");
    int num1= userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter 2nd number: ");
    int num2= userInput.nextInt();

    return (num1+num2);
  }

  public int cMinus(){
    System.out.println("Enter 1st number: ");
    int num1= userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter 2nd number: ");
    int num2= userInput.nextInt();

    return (num1-num2);
  }

  public char cSign(){
    System.out.println("Enter calculation sign: + - ");
    char sign= userInput.next().charAt(0);

    return sign;
  }

  public void calcResult(){

    char mySign= Calculator.this.cSign();

    if (mySign=='+'){
        System.out.println(" Your output for addition is " +Calculator.this.cAdd());
    }
    if (mySign=='-'){
        System.out.println(" Your output for subtraction is " +Calculator.this.cMinus());
    }
  }
}
```

After reading some articles and watching few youtube tutorials I decided to write a JUNIT test just to check the ADD method.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;


public class cADDTest extends TestCase {

  public static int actualResult=7;

  @Test
  public void TestcAdd(){
    /*Step1: Create instance of the class you are testing*/
    Calculator cl= new Calculator();

    /* Step2: The method of the class that you want to test*/
    cl.cAdd();

    /*Step3: Declare expected/ actual result*/
    int expectedResult=7;

    assertEquals(expectedResult,actualResult);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter 1st number: 
2
Enter 2nd number: 
3
PASSED: TestcAdd on null(cADDTest)

===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

**My question/confusion**: I hard coded the actual and expected result to be same, which is why it passed. However notice that I entered 2 and 3 which equals 5 and not 7. Was this a bad approach to test, if someone could explain what I should have tested and how that would be wonderful.

Thank You.

Comment: Jared your explanation makes sense. You are correct, it is taking 2 parameters. I have a follow up question. The code you have is int answer=c1.cAdd(3,5). If I follow that route then I will have to change my existing code. I am not using parameters in my actual Calculator code. Is there a way to test without making a change (meaning adding parameters to cAdd()) ?   public int cAdd(){
    System.out.println("Enter 1st number: ");
    int num1= userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter 2nd number: ");
    int num2= userInput.nextInt();

    return (num1+num2);
}  Thank You.

Comment: You may have a look at [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) which provides support for testing applications that interact with the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing different test frameworks (TestNG and JUnit 4). It looks like you want to use JUnit 4. Therefore change the import of the `Test` annotation and don't extend `TestCase`.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class cADDTest {

  public static int actualResult=7;

  @Test
  public void TestcAdd(){
    /*Step1: Create instance of the class you are testing*/
    Calculator cl= new Calculator();

    /* Step2: The method of the class that you want to test*/
    cl.cAdd();

    /*Step3: Declare expected/ actual result*/
    int expectedResult=7;

    assertEquals(expectedResult,actualResult);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly notice, instead of entering the values yourself during test execution, you want to have the values returned automatically.

To do this, you can try "mocking" certain method calls. What that means is when you are running the test, instead of actually calling a method (for example `userInput.nextInt()`), you can "mock" the call (meaning the logic in the method wont actually get called) and you can make the method call return any valid values you want, as long as it matches the return type of the method call.

So in your case, you can mock the first method call to `userInput.nextInt()` and have the method return `3`, and then mock the second method call to `userInput.nextInt()` and have the method return `4`. Then your test will check the results and validate. Remember mocking makes it so the method logic is not actually called so you wont have to enter any values into the console for the test.

So, the important question, how do you mock method calls? This is where you will have to study up a bit on mocking frameworks.

Here are some initial resources on mocking frameworks (try googling examples as well)

EasyMock - http://easymock.org/

PowerMock - https://code.google.com/p/powermock/

Mockito - http://mockito.org/  (this is seen a lot in stack overflow)

Finally, in the real world, you usually wont be reading / writing to the console, so Jared's  answer is closer to what you would see in a practical application (he deleted his answer but he modified the add method to take in parameters and return the sum of the two parameters, instead of reading from the console). But, that doesn't mean mocking isn't used. It's used all of the time and it is an important aspect in writing unit tests.